# Porting ctypes-based code snippet from linux to windows

Tags: python, ctypes

I have the following code that works under linux. I want to port it to Windows
 but i have no idea where to look for.

```
import os
import sys
import ctypes 
import ctypes.util
MAX_CHARS = 1000    # maximum number of characters to read

if __name__ == "__main__":
    libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6") # LINUX
    fd = libc.open(sys.argv[0], os.O_RDONLY)
    buffer = " " * MAX_CHARS
    num_chars_read = libc.read(fd, buffer, MAX_CHARS)
    print buffer[:num_chars_read]
    libc.close(fd)

    # ALL OF THIS GIVES WRONG DLL's 'UNDER WINDOWS
    #libc = ctypes.CDLL(ctypes.util.find_library('c'))
    #libc =  ctypes.windll.kernel32 # WINDOWS
    #libc =  ctypes.windll.user32 # WINDOWS
    #libc =  ctypes.windll.shell32 # WINDOWS
    #libc =  ctypes.windll.gdi32 # WINDOWS
#libc =  ctypes.cdll.msvcrt # WINDOWS
```

Any idea in which DLL i need to look for 'open' and 'read' calls?

Many thanks

Comment: Why not use the I/O facilities built into Python?

Comment: Why are you using libc to open and read files?  Python has native facilities for doing that.

Comment: I am aware of the native facilities but i am playing with ctypes for the moment and i am interested in much more system calls and these aren't available in stock python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[These slides](http://oss.netboxblue.com/pug/ctypes.html) indicate that this will work:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> libc = cdll.msvcrt
```

I can then access `libc.printf`, and `libc.fopen`, but not `open` or `read`, though `libc._open` and `libc._read` are available.  Perhaps an issue with calling conventions?

Comment: Replacing open, read and close by _open, _read and _close makes it work! 

Many thanks!